# Single JUnit5 test execution with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, junit5

I tried to run only one test class from Gradle. I used these commands:

```
gradle -Dtest.single=Junit5Test test
gradle test --tests ru.tests.runner.Junit5Test
```

But it runs all of the project's tests. I need to run only one test class. Here is my class:

```
public class Junit5Test {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
            .selectors(
                selectPackage("ru.tests.api")
            )
            .build();

        Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
        launcher.execute(request, new TestExecutionListener());
      }
    }
```

It works perfect by right-click run. I use

- IntellijIDEA 2017.1.5,
- Gradle,
- junitPlatformVersion = '1.0.0-M6',
- junitJupiterVersion = '5.0.0-M6'

Comment: It looks like your one tests builds a `Launcher` that executes all tests. So if you run that class, it makes sense that more than one test is executed.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your `Junit5Test` class is **not** a "test class".

Rather, it is a stand-alone application (i.e., a Java class with a `main()` method).

Thus, attempting to execute it as a "test" with Gradle will never work.

If you would like to run JUnit Jupiter tests (or any other tests that run on the JUnit Platform) with Gradle, you should use the [JUnit Platform Gradle Plugin](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle) (that's a link to the appropriate section of the JUnit 5 User Guide).

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with a simple test class using Gradle 4.4 and Junit5 / Jupiter: the --tests option is ignored and all tests are run instead. Would it be correct to say that :test task is actually substituted with :junitPlatformTest in this case, and since the latter doesn't have the --test option, one shouldn't wonder it has no effect?

Comment: Yes, that's correct: `junitPlatformTest` is a completely different task than the built-in `test` task.

Comment: If you want to configure which tests are run via the `junitPlatformTest` task, you'll need to configure selectors and/or filters via the `junitPlatform` configuration, which is fully documented in the JUnit 5 User Guide.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by replacing

```
gradle -Dtest.single=Junit5Test test
```

with

```
gradle -DjunitPlatformTest.single=Junit5Test test
```