# How to run only specific tests with Gradle and JUnit 5?

Tags: gradle, junit5

Using Gradle and its JUnit 4 support, I can choose a specific test using the `--tests` option like this:

```
$ ./gradlew test --tests de.mp.BarMT
```

This option is ineffective when using the JUnit 5 Gradle task. It is ignored silently when using the `test` tasks from the command line. The true work is done by `junitPlatformTest` anyway, and it does not support the option:

```
$ ./gradlew clean junitPlatformTest --tests de.mp.BarMT
…
Problem configuring task :junitPlatformTest from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--tests'.
```

Does the JUnit 5 plugin support choosing specific tests?

Comment: Related to ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508263/single-junit5-test-execution-with-gradle?

Comment: That’s true. Almost a duplicate, I would say (only that I have real tests, I promise). Weird it did not show up in the search while creating the question.

Comment: Native Gradle support is almost here. The current plan is to include it in Gradle 4.6 (cf. https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/4116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering myself… A lot of time has passed, new versions came, and I can confirm that with Gradle 5.4.1 and JUnit Jupiter Platform 1.4.2, the simple configuration:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

will allow running single tests as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31468902/2621917, even when using weird names (from Kotlin):

```
gradle test --tests 'HtmlForwardInterceptorTest.should forward requests'
```